# How to search for ".somefile" on MacOS from terminal?

Tags: linux, macos, file, terminal

I want to search for hidden files (e.g. file name is: ".somefile") anywhere in any directory from terminal.
Is this a right command ?

`find / -name ".somefile"`

Bonus question - is it possible to exclude `Permission denied` lines from a search output? (`| grep -v "Permission denied"` did not work right out of box)...

Thanks.

Comment: `find / -name ".somefile" 2 > /dev/null`

Comment: This will probably be closed soon, because it's not a programming question and therefore off-topic (next time, post questions like this in SuperUser or Ask Different instead). But, the answers to your questions are: 1) Yes, and 2) just send `stderr` to `/dev/null`.

Comment: Your command’s right, just include `sudo` in front of it to get rid of permission denied.

Comment: Thank you all. Just a quick note @arkascha : `2 > /dev/null` was giving error to me (`find: 2: unknown primary or operator`) while `2> /dev/null` did not (notice one 'space' less in second command after number 2).

Answer (score 0):

Update Index For Locate:
`sudo /usr/libexec/locate.updatedb`

Locate:
`locate *.somefile`